# Returning a module exports with object - Error AsyncFunction

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a helper to store all of my data and want to import it. Although, it either comes in as undefined or [AsyncFunction]

I am using Express, and there could be a conflict on the way I'm importing it. Not sure.

**tags.js**

```
module.exports = () => {

    return {
      'test',
      'test1',
      'test3'
}
```

**main.js**

```
const allTags = require('../../src/helpers/tags')

router.get('/test8', (req, res) => {

     console.log( allTags ) // [AsyncFunction]

})
```

If I add `allTags()` the result is not `'Promise { undefined } '`

Comment: are you trying to export an array or an object?

Comment: @JBaczuk Trying to export an object

Comment: `{
      'test',
      'test1',
      'test3'
}` is not a valid object

Comment: Then can I assign it to a variable like let tags = {} and then module export tags? I've tried that but kept getting same error.

Comment: that would work too, but you have something else going on here, there is not enough info to troubleshoot

Comment: "*the result is not `'Promise { undefined } '`*" - then what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to export a function, just export the array itself.

```
module.exports = [
  'test',
  'test1',
  'test3'
]
```

Comment: It still gives me the same [AsyncFunction]

Comment: It was the path!! Thank you so much.